# Intuition behind the inverse of the copula density $\frac{1}{c(u,v)}$

Tags: probability, density-function, intuition, copula

If the inverse of a probability $\frac{1}{p(x)}$ represents the unpredictability or surprisal of a sample from random variable $X$,
then what is the intuition behind the point-wise inverse of the copula density, $\frac{1}{c(u,v)}$, where $U$ and $V$ are marginal distributions?